# Dropdown MVC4 Bind Default data from database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a dropdown in which datas are binding from database. its works fine in which I need to display one particular item a first value in the dropdown.
For example dropdown with arun,siva,kumar in which siva must be at the first place note three datas coming from database. 
***View***:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

    <fieldset>

        <legend>Multi-Select Demo</legend>

        <div class="editor-field">

           @Html.DropDownList("FirstName", Model.SelectNameList);

            )

        </div>

        <p>

            <input type="submit" value="Save" />

        </p>

    </fieldset>

}
```

Controller

```
  public ActionResult List()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(con);
            Patient model = new Patient();
            List<Patient> objUserDetails = new List<Patient>();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Patients", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            var studentCount = dt.Rows.Count;
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    Patient userinfo = new Patient();
                    userinfo.FirstName = dt.Rows[i]["FirstName"].ToString();
                    userinfo.PatientId = Convert.ToInt16(dt.Rows[i]["PatientId"]);
                    objUserDetails.Add(userinfo);
                }
            }

            model.SelectNameList = new SelectList(objUserDetails, "PatientId", "FirstName");

            return View(model);
        }
```

I want the sixth data of my list as first data in dropdown

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17806021/1873002

Answer (score 0):

One option can be to use `jquery`. You can set id to your `dropdownlist` and then use that id in `document.ready` handler to set selected index for `dropdownlist`

Assign Id to your `dropdownlist`

```
@Html.DropDownList("FirstName", Model.SelectNameList,new { id = "drpdwnID" });
```

Jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#drpdwnID option:eq(4)").attr('selected', true)//4 is the index you want to set as selected
})
```