# How to set selected item to a dynamic dropdown list in Edit Mode MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
@if (ViewBag.language != null)
{
    foreach (var item in ViewBag.language)
    {
        <div class="control-label col-md-2">Language</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.DropDownList("LanguageId", null, new { @class = "form-control" },@item.LanguageID)
        </div>
    }
}
```

the `ViewBag.Langauge` contains the `LangaugeID` and `foreach` iteration I want to set the dropdownlist selected value as value of `@item.langaugeID`

```
ViewBag.LanguageId = new SelectList(db.Languages, "LanguageId", "LanguageName");
```

Contains all the languages in database

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    int languageid = StudentLanuguages[i];
    List<tblStudentLanguageMapping> StudentLan = new List<tblStudentLanguageMapping>();
    StudentLan = (from a in db.tblStudentLanguageMappings 
                  where a.StudentLanguageMappingId == languageid
                  select a).ToList();
    std.AddRange(StudentLan);
}
ViewBag.language = std;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC5 Razor html.dropdownlistfor set selected when value is in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37407811/mvc5-razor-html-dropdownlistfor-set-selected-when-value-is-in-array)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select a default value in dropdownlistfor MVC 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805265/select-a-default-value-in-dropdownlistfor-mvc-4)

Comment: Thank you @StephenMuecke my question was  the same and the link was helpful , but  i didnt get the output as i expected  can you please provide a sample code  so that the value in **@item.LangaugeId** can be set selected in the dropdown list

Comment: @DylanSlabbinck thanks for replying  but sir,  actually my requirement is like  I  have a loop and for each iteration the dropdown list should be  generated and a value should be set selected. I have that value in **@item.LanguageId** what i dont know is how to pass it to the dropdown in the view itself

Comment: @Akuria, You need to read the dupe. You cannot use `@Html.DropDownList("LanguageId", null, ...`. Use `@Html.DropDownListFor() and strongly bind to a model (and that model will contain a collection of objects containing a property to bind to)

Comment: i got it by a much lesser effort don't know whether its the right way to do just by including a javascript   { <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetSelectedVal(id) {
            debugger;
            var ddlLang = "Id_" + id;
            $("#"+ddlLang).val(id);
        }
    </script> }